# Find the closure of $A=\{(-1)^{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Find the closure of $A=\{(-1)^{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 1\}$ aubset of $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology.

I believe this $\bar A=\{1,-1\}\cup A$

Suppose $x\in \{1,-1\}\cup A$

Suppose $I$ is an open interval containing $x$, open intervals are a basis for standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ so to show $x\in \bar A$, need to show that for any open interval, $I\cap A\neq \emptyset$

Either $x\in \{1, -1\}$ or $x\in A$

if $x\in A$ then $I\cap A\neq \emptyset $ since $x\in I\cap A$

If $x\in \{1,-1\}$, then I need to show there exist $a\in A$ that are in an open neighborhood around $x$

I believe I need to show that, $a_n=(-1)^{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n}$ converges to $-1$

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $n>\frac{1}{2(\epsilon-2)}$

then

$\vert (-1)^{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n}-(-1)\vert=\vert -1+1-\frac{1}{2n}\vert$

$=\vert\frac{1}{2n}\vert<\frac{1}{\frac{2}{2\epsilon}}=\epsilon$

thus converges, so for any $\epsilon$,

there exists $a\in A$ such that $a\in I\cap A$,

thus $I\cap A\neq \emptyset$

So $x=-1\in \bar A$

And that, $x_n=(-1)^{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}$ converges to $1$

Let $\epsilon > 0$, let $n>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$

then $\vert (-1)^{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-1\vert=\vert 1-1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\vert -\frac{1}{2n+1}\vert$

$=\vert \frac{1}{2n+1}\vert< \frac{1}{2\frac{1}{2\epsilon}+1}=\frac{1}{\frac{\epsilon+1}{\epsilon}}=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+1}<\epsilon$

So there exists $a\in A$ arbitrarily close to $1$, thus $x=1\in \bar A$

So I believe I have $\{1,-1\}\cup A\subseteq \bar A$

But I'm not sure how to show $\bar A\subseteq \{1,-1\}\cup A$

Comment: Reptile.You have shown -1,1 are limit points. Think it is fairly obvious that no other $x \in \mathbb{R}$ qualifies. You can show that  $x \not = \pm 1$ is not a limit points, if you want .

Comment: @Peter Szilas My definition of closure doesn't use limit points. The definition I have is that the closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed subsets containing $A$. I also have this theorem, $x\in \bar A$ if and only if for every open set, $U\subseteq X$ containing $x$, $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$

Comment: Reptile. If you assume $\{-1,1\}\cup A$ is closed then your last line is obvious with your definition.

Comment: @Peter Szilas So I just need to show $A$ is closed then?

Comment: $A$ is not closed. $\{-1,1\}\cup A$ is closed. @AColoredReptile

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy How would I show that is closed? My definition of closed is that the complement is open.

Comment: @AColoredReptile $(\{-1,1\}\cup A)^C=(-\infty,-2/3)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}((-1)^{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n},(-1)^{2n+3}-\frac{1}{2n+2})\cup(-1,0)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}((-1)^{2n}-\frac{1}{2n-1},(-1)^{2n+2}-\frac{1}{2n+1})\cup(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @AColoredReptile Under the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, this union of open interval is open, so its complement, which is the closure you've found, is closed.